# grub misses windows10 OS after fedora 33 installation

Tags: grub, fedora-33

*I apologize, this is probably the most asked quesion. I tried again to do all suggestions, just as I do after every reinstall, and it did not work again. I tried to study grub/grub2 multiple times, yet it seems that what worked last time won't ever work next time*

Older installations uses legacy bios, new fedora 33 uses efi. After installation(everything default maybe except partitioning), there was only fedora 33 in grub2.

```
sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

Produces

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[62570]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5501: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[56813]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5501: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[62570]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5501: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[56813]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5501: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[62570]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5560: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[56813]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5560: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[62570]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5560: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[56813]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5560: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[62570]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5626: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[56813]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5626: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[62570]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5626: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[56813]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5626: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[62570]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5685: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[56813]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5685: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[62570]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5685: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[56813]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 5685: grub2-probe
Found Fedora 30 (Thirty) on /dev/mapper/ssd--vg-f30root
Found Fedora release 26 (Twenty Six) on /dev/mapper/ssd--vg-fedora26system
done
```

Surprisingly running OS is not detected, but after reboot in fear, fedora 33 is still in grub. After that I'm at least able to boot to older fedora 30. Fedora 26(very old and just undeleted system kept just for sake of having access to old configs if I happen to use them) was discovered, however not shown in grub. No idea why, but I did not boot it at least 2 years so I don't care that much. Windows 10 not detected. I tried to compare `/etc/grub.d` to older installation of fedora 30, and there ins't windows mention in neither of them, yet older distro was able to eventually detect it. Windows partition is not encrypted.

Another trick I remember I had to use before was mounting ntfs partitions and rerun `grub2-mkconfig`. Did not help this time.

I tried also grub-customizer, but it detects only fedora 30. Not 33(but that's probably hidden), not 26, not windows10. So that's yet another detection permutation. I left it here not to make any more issues.

I did not resort yet to copy-pasting randomly found code from web, so I did not try to write some custom stub in /etc/grub.d

---

Can someone suggest, what is correct up-to-day way to detect ALL existing operating systems (and still bootable via fedora 30 grub)? Thanks.

Comment: what is windows bios mode : legacy or uefi

Comment: OK, might be the point, that I had mostly legacy systems. So I reinstalled fedora 33 to legacy as well. Small improvement!  'grub2-mkconfig' command from question now detects: windows10, fedora 30 and fedora 26, but not self (better). Command grub-customizer detects fedora 30 and windows 10, not self or fedora 26 (better). However after reboot I'm presented only with windows10 and fedora 33 (significantly worse, as I cannot loging to my old installation which I still use for work). Well I can boot from specific drive to avoid f33 grub issues, but still. What is the correct command to fix this?

Comment: Regarding legacy/uefi: f26 is definitely legacy, windows definitely legacy, f33 definitely legacy now. f30 no idea, but probably legacy as well.  And weird thing is, that f30 is now not shown (while detected) while before it was shown in grub and accessible. Both w10 and f30 are in `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` yet only w10 is shown.